# How to check for value in a list of dictionaries in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, foreach, contains

What expression can return a boolean if any dictionary within a list contains a particular value?

Imagine this, but without having to reference each item in the list individually:

```vb
(Dict_List(0).ContainsValue(value) or Dict_List(1).ContainsValue(value) or Dict_List(2).ContainsValue(value))=False
```

Ideally, if the value is not already in one of the dictionaries, along with  several other conditions; then the code would add another dictionary. I know a foreach might work in this case, but a single expression would be faster at runtime, and it would be nice to know this just as a best practice.

Comment: You should check whether a Dictionary contains a Key, rather then a specific value. Anyway, see [IEnumerable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) LINQ's extension methods: Any(), All(), Where(), FirstOrDefault()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two LINQ options that come to mind:

```
If Dict_List.SelectMany(Function(d) d.Values).Contains(value) Then
```

or:

```
If Dict_List.Any(Function(d) d.ContainsValue(value)) Then
```

The first option gets the values from each `Dictionary` and concatenates them all into a single list, then checks that list for a matching value.  The second option checks each `Dictionary` individually and returns `True` if any individual check returns `True`.  Being LINQ, they both avoid pointlessly checking the rest of the values if a match is found.

Comment: Thanks! I found the second one more useful since I can reference all the items in a list in an expression as if there was only one. But this was exactly what I needed, thanks!